# Creating web forms in runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

This is a question of a more general nature. I'm building a system that can create dynamically forms and reports during runtime. For that purpose we're using data dictionary for storing data and XML definitions as blueprints for creating forms and reports as needed. We're using WWF Rule Engine for necessary business logic.

Right now I'm evaluating what would be the best approach to upgrade my system to allow creating web applications from my XML definition. I'm thinking of creating master page that would have a menu of defined forms and clicking on them would render them to the user.

Web forms are different beast than win forms. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go here with ASP.NET MVC if possible - you could create the form on client side for better performance (for example using jQuery).

On the other side - you can create the forms in the View and send it to the user according to the blueprint. It's plain HTML creation.

Anyhow, if you're using ASP.NET Web forms you can iterate through the XML, interpret it and add then add to the form. It would be more complicated I think.

Comment: Do you have any link that would demonstrate something like this using MVC?

Comment: you could try here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926934/dynamic-runtime-generated-forms-in-asp-net-mvc